Runs like a button, but doesn't look like a button
Is there a way to associate an operator with a value (IMAGE, this case, in example below) without changing it to look like a 'button'.  Would like it to look the same visually(as the example), but have it be clickable to run an operator.


one way, it seems...
the key is in the emboss=False.
running code example:
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Your operator logic here
        return {'FINISHED'}



class SimplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Simple Panel"
    bl_idname = "PT_SimplePanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tools'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.alignment = "LEFT"
        
        # Customizing the operator appearance
        row.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, icon='NONE', emboss=False)
        


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```


It's not clear, how you put an image under it from the answer. ...or what it has to do with images anyway...
